# String - объект, а как получить ссылку?

Tags: java, ссылки, объекты, строки

Только начал изучать Java. Прошу объяснить.

```
String firstString = new String("This is first string"); 

String secondString = firstString;
```

На сколько мне известно, во втором случае в переменной **secondString** должна быть **ссылка на объект firstString**. Но создается копия объекта. Совсем иначе обстоит ситуация с другими объектами. Почему? Ведь, String тоже объект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторая переменная ссылается на ту же самую строку, ничего не копируется. В Java и C# строки являются *неизменяемыми*, поэтому их необязательно копировать при передаче в другой метод, присваивании переменных и т.п. Любое изменение строки будет приводить к созданию нового экземпляра, поэтому, если вы измените `firstString`, значение `secondString` не изменится, хотя изначально они ссылались на один и тот же экземпляр строки.

Строки не уникальны в этом поведении. Если вы создадите неизменяемый класс, все методы которого будут возвращать новый экземпляр, а состояние экземпляров которого нельзя изменить извне, то у этого класса будет такое же поведение, как и у строки.